# Configure outgoing IP address on Debian

Tags: networking, debian, ip, vps, debian-jessie

I have a VPS that is hosted by ovh.com and I added a new IP address.

- The first one is **51.254.117.162**
- The one I added is **46.105.47.86**

I searched far and wide on the internet, but I can't find a way to set my VPS so the outgoing traffic uses the second IP address.

I use Debian 8 (Jessie). Here is my /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

address 46.105.47.86
```

Here is the ifconfig output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fa:16:3e:81:53:07
          inet addr:51.254.117.162  Bcast:51.254.117.162  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::f816:3eff:fe81:5307/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15346 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11246 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1214754 (1.1 MiB)  TX bytes:13473776 (12.8 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:57720 (56.3 KiB)  TX bytes:57720 (56.3 KiB)
```

Here is the ip a s output:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:81:53:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 51.254.117.162/32 brd 51.254.117.162 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe81:5307/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Here is the ip r s output:

```
default via 51.254.112.1 dev eth0
51.254.112.1 dev eth0  scope link
```

I would like to **permanently** use 46.105.47.86 as the outgoing IP. Could someone please explain me how to do so?

Comment: If your application does not pick a source IP (some can be configured most work unbound by default) Linux will pick the source IP address associated with the route it uses to reach the target. So in case you want to reach all destinations with another source Ip modify the default route. You need to use ip route. Let us see `ip a s` and `ip r s`.

Comment: I edited my post to add those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed to a new IP address, or do you now have 2 IPs and gateways?

Changing your IP - Your current configuration is for DHCP... if you've been given a new IP for your VPS just re-requesting a DHCP lease should do it - `dhclient -v eth0` .  Take that `address` line out it isn't doing any good.

You now have 2 IP addresses -

OK, so assuming you have been given static IP settings (IP, netmask, gateway) for TWO IP addresses/gateways it depends on what device your second IP is attached to/associated wtih.  It may be eth1, or it could be an alias to eth0 - eth0:1 (linode does this).

You want your `/etc/network/interfaces` file to look something like this - the actual device identifier may be different for you - check it with `/sbin/ifconfig -a`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 172.16.12.123 
  netmask 255.255.255.0
 # gateway 172.16.12.1

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
  address 192.168.234.56
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.234.1
```

Change the IPs and device names to match what you really have.

To change which device is the default gateway, simply move the comment from one gateway statement to the other and restart networking. ONLY LEAVE ONE GATEWAY STATEMENT UN-COMMENTED!!

Comment: Thank you, adding that eth0:1 interface did the trick :D !